# NGINX cache mis-behaving causing the system to go into a frenzy

Tags: linux, nginx, centos6, cache

We're using CentOS/nginx fastcgi_cache to cache requests to PHP files on our server. This file gets accessed very often and also updates very often as such it has 1s cache.

Usually when looking through the access log we'll see something like this:

```
00:01 REQUEST 1 "EXPIRE"
00:01 REQUEST 2 "HIT"
00:01 REQUEST 3 "HIT"
00:02 REQUEST 4 "EXPIRE"
00:02 REQUEST 5 "HIT"
00:02 REQUEST 6 "HIT"
```

When the problem occurs something happens to nginx and suddenly the log starts looking like this (all expire even though same second):

```
00:01 REQUEST 1 "EXPIRE"
00:01 REQUEST 2 "EXPIRE"
00:01 REQUEST 3 "EXPIRE"
00:02 REQUEST 4 "EXPIRE"
00:02 REQUEST 5 "EXPIRE"
00:02 REQUEST 6 "EXPIRE"
```

Important note: Just before this happens php-fpm reports: 
WARNING: [pool www] server reached max_children setting (35), consider raising it
NOTICE: Terminating ...
NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 27544
NOTICE: ready to handle connections

(This is not normal behavior and is very rare)

I've tried restarting php-fpm mid work to see if it affects the cache - no go.
I've also tried stress testing the specific files that gets called often and I can't make the system go crazy.. 
Also verified the cache-key is configured correctly.

Anyone has any ideas what other possibilities exist here? Anything else I can look into?

P.S To fix it when it happens we stop the requests for the file and restart the service and it works again..

Thanks for the help,
Alon

Comment: What does this PHP script do? If it's just returning data, can you not use something like Redis which is O(1)? If your script is just getting and setting data.

Comment: It returns some data from a DB.. fairly basic. 

We can use Redis to store said data and improve the script but that makes it so we can run the script many more times than it should rather than understand why the caching acts up..

(if I understood you correctly?:) Thanks for the help

Comment: My suggestion was to not interact with the database at all. Redis is O(1) which is as good as it gets, if you're getting the same data very frequently, and setting data almost as frequently, Redis will do it many times faster than any database. If you'd rather debug the current system, fair enough, but I think Redis will suit your purpose very well.

Comment: I agree that Redis might hide\fix the problem here but the current stack works very well 99.9% of the time..

Thank you for the suggestion :)